# How do I get an array of single attribute from each documents

Tags: mongodb

I apologize for unspecified question but I really don't have any idea what it is called.

Let's say I have "documents" attribute in "owner" documents like this

```
owner : [{
  "_id": "1111",
  "documents": [{
      "file_name": "126789AP.pdf", "_id": "00A1"
    },{
      "file_name": "126789CE.pdf", "_id": "00A2"
    },{
      "file_name": "514132AP.pdf", "_id": "00A3"
    }],
  "name": "Dalton"
},{
  "_id": "2222",
  "documents": {
      "file_name": "126789AP.pdf", "_id": "00B1"
  },
  "name":"Mason"
}]
```

I need to get an documents output from every owner like this

```
documents : [{ 
    "file_name": "126789AP.pdf", "_id": "00A1"
  },{ 
    "file_name": "126789CE.pdf", "_id": "00A2"
  },{ 
    "file_name": "514132AP.pdf", "_id": "00A3"
  },{ 
    "file_name": "126789AP.pdf", "_id": "00B1"
  }]
```

I've look up its doc and tried use find() and aggregate() but it seems I missing something so it turned out as arrays of "documents" object but I don't think mapReduce is the best way to do so I seek for help.

[EDIT]

here is find()

```
db.owner.find({ "documents":{$exists:true} },{documents:1})
```

and here's aggregate()

```
db.owner.aggregate([{$project:{documents:1}},{$match:{documents:{$exists:true}}‌​}])
```

[EDIT 2] I finally figure it out! Here is my answer

```
db.students.aggregate([
  { $unwind : "$documents" },
  { $match : { "documents" : { $exists : true }}},
  { $project : { documents : 1 }}
])
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried for both the `find()` and `aggregate()` queries?

Comment: here is find()
[db.owner.find({
        "documents":{$exists:true}
    },{documents:1})]

and here's aggregate()
[db.onwer.aggregate([{$project:{documents:1}},{$match:{documents:{$exists:true}}}])]

Comment: Please use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35333937/edit) link on your question to include additional code, not in comments.

Comment: sorry, I'm new to this

Comment: I want documents from every owner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a basic loop in `javaScript`:

```
owner = [{
  "_id": "1111",
  "documents": [{
      "file_name": "126789AP.pdf", "_id": "00A1"
    },{
      "file_name": "126789CE.pdf", "_id": "00A2"
    },{
      "file_name": "514132AP.pdf", "_id": "00A3"
    }],
  "name": "Dalton"
},{
  "_id": "2222",
  "documents": {
      "file_name": "126789AP.pdf", "_id": "00B1"
  },
  "name":"Mason"
}];

var documents = owner.map(function(obj){ 
     return obj.documents;
});
console.log(documents);
```

Comment: I'm currently using that but I need the best way to response to the documents request that should return only array of documents object

Comment: what is `.map()` and where I can use it

Comment: In `JavaScript` the `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: I don't understand your code. Could you please tell me what is `obj` `documents` and `owner` referring to?

Comment: `owner` is an array that holds your actual response coming from the database here.`documents` is an array holds the result you are expecting. And `obj` refers to each element of `owner`. Here `map` method is pushing  only **documents** property from `owner`

Comment: I've tried it.  I did fine with `name` attribute but when comes to `documents` it return `undefined`

Comment: I accept and appreciate your answer. I will try to figure it out.

Thanks for your time